# GCD dispatch_sync priority over previously queued dispatch_async

Tags: multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have a class that wraps a data model and is accessed/modified by multiple threads. I need to make sure modification to data model is synchronized. I am using a dispatch_queue_create(..., DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL). This is working really well for my needs.

Most of the methods on my class internally call "dispatch_async(queue, ^{...});". There are a few places where I need to return a snapshot result. This is a simplified example of how that looks:

```
- (NSArray*) getSomeData {
    __block NSArray* result = nil;

    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
         ... Do Stuff ...
         result = blah.blah;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, lets assume that 5 "async tasks" are queued and one is currently executing. Now a "sync" task is scheduled. When will the "sync task" execute?

What I would like to have happen is "sync task" is executed ahead of any pending "async tasks". Is this what happens by default? If not is there a way to priority queue the "sync task"?

BTW,

I know I can set an overall queue priority but that is not what this question is about. For me queue priority normal is just fine. I just want my synchronous tasks to happen before any pending asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a generic setting for "perform sync tasks first" or for setting relative priority between enqueued blocks in a single queue. To recap what may be obvious, a serial queue is going to work like a *queue*: first in, first out. That said, it's pretty easy to conceive of how you might achieve this effect using multiple queues and targeting. For example:

```
realQueue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
asyncOpsQueue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_set_target_queue(asyncOpsQueue, realQueue);

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dispatch_async(asyncOpsQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Doing async work block %@", @(i));
        sleep(1);
    });
}

// Then whenever you have high priority sync work to do, stop the async
// queue, do your work, and then restart it.
dispatch_suspend(asyncOpsQueue);
dispatch_sync(realQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"Doing sync work block");
});

dispatch_resume(asyncOpsQueue);
```

One thing to know is that an executing block effectively can't be canceled/suspended/terminated (from the outside) once it's begun. So any async enqueued block that's in flight has to run to completion before your sync block can start, but this arrangement of targeting allows you to pause the flow of async blocks and inject your sync block. Note that it also doesn't matter that you're doing a sync block. It could, just as easily, be an async block of high priority, but in that case you would probably want to move the `dispatch_resume` into the block itself.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This looks like to nice solution. I will implement it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I've implemented it and tested it a lot and does exactly what I needed.